# ParentalKey not linked to all subclasses in Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have created 3 abstract model classes:
`SimpleContent` (only keeping title,subtitle and a summary. All text based)
`VisualContent` (an image, a richtext field)
`Ctalinkitem` (for adding a url, could be a page, external or a document)

I want to create another classes that could include a combination of these classes to form a 'module-like' class.

e.g. `RichContent` will have all 3 of them
TextLinkContent will have SimpleContent and Ctalinkitem

I created a class like this

```
class RichContent (SimpleContent, VisualContent, Ctalinkitem):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then I try to create a link to a page

```
class LandingPageRichContent(Orderable, RichContent):
    page = ParentalKey('LandingPage', related_name='landingpage_richcontent_link')
```

and then I add this to the page as an `InlinePanel`

```
LandingPage.content_panels = [
    FieldPanel('title',classname='full title'),
    InlinePanel(LandingPage,'landingpage_richcontent_link', label='Rich Content'),classname='full',heading='Rich Content'),
]
```

I made the migrations and no error. However when I try to create a `LandingPage`, I could only see fields from `SimpleContent`. I couldn't see any input field for `VisualContent` and `Ctalinkitem`.

If I change the declaratioon of `RichContent` to:

```
class RichContent (VisualContent, SimpleContent, Ctalinkitem):
```

Then I can only see fields from `VisualContent`.

I wonder if I am doing the right approach? Is there any solution to get around this?

Comment: Thank you @michaelpri. Sorry it's my first time posting here I will pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide an explicit `panels` definition on `RichContent`, possibly something like:

```
RichContent.panels = SimpleContent.panels + VisualContent.panels + Ctalinkitem.panels
```

Wagtail is able to auto-generate a panels definition in some circumstances, but this is rather limited (for example, it doesn't recognise page chooser panels) - and in particular, if you already have a `panels` definition on each of your superclasses, then it won't automatically combine these into a single list. Instead, what you're seeing here is Python's multiple inheritance rules causing the `panels` attribute from the first superclass to override the later ones.

Comment: It works! Thank you @gasman. I wasn't aware that panels was overridden by the first superclass. To achieve functionality like this, am I using the right approach? or is there any other solution? I would like to have some pre-defined frontend panel which will include different combination of classes)